# C# get sequences of numbers from string containing numbers and words?

Tags: c#, string, substring

Given a string like "10 of 15 points" or "0 of 1 point" how would I get the first number in one variable and the second number in a second variable?

Comment: Do you want the first number, or first charactar?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In the examples above, I want to get the number 10 and 15 for the first example and 0 and 1 for the second example.

Comment: For example, if your string was "foo 90 70" would you still want the "90" or would you want the "fo"?

Comment: I figured that is what you would want. If you only wanted to get the first 2 characters, which would be "fo", you could just .SubString() it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Split` and `LINQ`:

```
var str = "10 of 15 points";
var numbers = str.Split().Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit))
              .Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

This would return a `List<int>` that contains `10` and `15`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Is there a reason you use `var` instead of `string`?

Comment: @Keavon If you used a string, I'm pretty sure you couldn't do it.

Comment: @Keavon no but I'm usually use `var` it's shorter and easy to use.it makes life much easier,especially when using long type names :)

Comment: @Dozer789 I think he meant the first variable (str)

Comment: That's a nice tip to know.

Comment: @Keavon if you see `var` for the first time then you should definitely take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: I've seen `var` before but I wasn't aware that I should use it as a shortcut like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp = "10 of 15 points".Split(" ");

var num1 = int.Parse(temp[0])
var num2 = int.Parse(temp[2])
```